# Give dataprep product access to user via terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-dataprep, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm having a terraform project and want to give user access to dataprep product. I don't see any resource present in Terraform [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/google_iam_policy.html)

But it looks like its not documented/supported.

Ideas?